# how to read report id in the first byte from hid data for the hid device?

Tags: c, embedded, hid

I am using ftdi chip VNC2 and scan data using two barcode readers, however, one receives 8-byte data and the other receives 9-byte data. And I use wireshark to check the package they received, then I found that the 9-byte-barcode reader had one more byte (here the report id is 0x03) before the other 8-byte barcode reader. And the one more byte is report id that I found in wireshark capture.

However, I tried to get the report descriptor by sending request from USB host (i.e. VNC2), however I got different information (they are (desc_dev.wValue >> 8) & 0xff = 0x5F;  desc_dev.wValue & 0xff = 0x73;).

My question is how could I get the correct report id (i.e., 0x03)? could anyone give me some suggestions? Thank you so much!

This is the code requesting for "GET_DESCRIPTOR" code value modified from example code of VNC2.

```
// host controller device descriptor
usb_deviceRequest_t desc_dev;

// user ioctl to find control endpoint on this device  
hc_iocb.ioctl_code = VOS_IOCTL_USBHOST_DEVICE_GET_CONTROL_ENDPOINT_HANDLE;
hc_iocb.handle.dif = ifDev;
hc_iocb.get = &epCtrl;

status = vos_dev_ioctl(hUSBHOST_1, &hc_iocb);

if (status != USBHOST_OK) {
    break;
}

desc_dev.bmRequestType = USB_BMREQUESTTYPE_HOST_TO_DEV | USB_BMREQUESTTYPE_CLASS | USB_BMREQUESTTYPE_DEVICE;
desc_dev.bRequest = 0x06; // 0x06 means GET_DESCRIPTOR
            
hc_iocb.ioctl_code = VOS_IOCTL_USBHOST_DEVICE_SETUP_TRANSFER;
hc_iocb.handle.ep = epCtrl;
hc_iocb.set = &desc_dev;

status = vos_dev_ioctl(hUSBHOST_1, &hc_iocb);
            
if (status != USBHOST_OK) {
    break;
}

hid_reportid_2 = desc_dev.wValue & 0xff;
hid_reportid_3 = (desc_dev.wValue >> 8) & 0xff;
```

This is the code to get report descriptor modified from example code for hid device of VNC2.

```
hid_iocb.descriptorType = USB_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_REPORT;
hid_iocb.descriptorIndex = USB_HID_DESCRIPTOR_INDEX_ZERO;
hid_iocb.Length = 0x40;
hid_iocb.get.data = &transfer_buf[0]; 
hid_iocb.ioctl_code = VOS_IOCTL_USBHOSTHID_GET_DESCRIPTOR;
            
status = vos_dev_ioctl(hUSBHOST_HID, &hid_iocb);
            
if (status != USBHOSTHID_OK)
{
    break;
}

hid_protocoltype = hid_iocb.protocolType;
hid_reporttype = hid_iocb.reportType;
hid_reportid = hid_iocb.reportID;
```

From the code above, hid_protocoltype = 0x6F; hid_reporttype = 0x73; hid_reportid = 0x5F; hid_reportid_2 = 0x00; hid_reportid_3 = 0x00.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @ryyker
I add some parts of codes as shown above, plz take a look and give some suugestions, thank you so much!

Comment: I have removed my close vote.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the specific application note or other documentation that you are using to guide you in the code you have produced so far? (eg, you say _"... from example code of VNC2"_ in two places.   comment a link to that document.)

Comment: @ryyker This is the example code that I took as reference.
[link](https://ftdichip.com/firmware/) and [link](https://ftdichip.com/firmware/vnc2-tools/) In the folder of sample code (Samples/V2.0.2-SP2/USBHost), I use three example mentioned above ( I tried to modify two of three into one, they are "USBHostHID2" and "USBHostHID". And the other one is "USBHostHIDKbd". ) Thank you so much!

Comment: @ryyker Here are some example codes I found on github, but might modified part of the original code. However, I put the link as follows. Thanks again! [link](https://github.com/mvvproject/ReVerSE-U16/blob/master/u16_zet/vnc2/USBHostHID2.c) . [link](https://github.com/mvvproject/ReVerSE-U16/blob/master/u16_speccy/vnc2/USBHostHIDKbd/USBHostHIDKbd.c)